# How to find overall HTML Page Size

Tags: html, size

I need to find overall page size (CSS, JS, Images and HTML) after page load. Saving page do not save dynamically loaded images, so unable to find the exact page size. Any info for online tool or browser plugin will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Firebug, and also Yslow Extenstions, in order to view the performance of the web sites.  in btw you can follow this standards [Yahoo guidelines for Speedup PageLoading](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

1. Yslow : [YSlow homePage](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)
2. FireBug :[Firebug tool](http://getfirebug.com/)
3. FIddler Web Debugging tool [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 2):

Firebug or the built-in Developer Tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I just developed a Chrome extension to answer this: [Page Size Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-size-inspector/oepnndnpjiahgkljgbohnnccmokgcoln). It reports page size, cache usage, network requests, load time.

Open source at [GitHub](https://github.com/tomimick/chrome-ext-page-size).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install addons web developer on firefox

from here

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/

and from web developer toolbar select information/view document size

have fun